# provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.)

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de acceder remotamente a travez de una VPN a un servidor SQL server 2005 desde una estancia de SQL express 2016 en windows 11, mas sin embargo al intentar conectar me manda el siguiente error:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.)

al tratar de entrar a otro servidor que esta en SQL server 2016 conecta sin ningun tipo de problema, incluso puedo crear servisores vinculados sin problemas en el 2016, pero en SQL server 2005 no puedo, he investigado un al respecto y pareciera ser algo relacionado con los protocolos SSL y TLS pero no he encontrado alguna solucion en concreto,alguien podria ayudarme con alguna solucion o a alguien le ha pasado igual?

Comment: ¿cómo o desde dónde estás _intentando conectar_?

Comment: desde una estancia SQL en una laptop de mi casa a travez de forticlient a el servidor del trabajo

Comment: No existe tal cosa como "estancia SQL". Por favor explicalo con otras palabras. Si pregunto es porque hay muchas maneras de conectarse y a tu pregunta le falta contexto. Para más información lee [how-to-ask]. Un saludo.